# c# file or folder notification event

Tags: c#, file, events

I am developing an application which will invoke a file created by third party application, everytime the file was placed in default location defined by third party application, I want to change the default file location on the fly, I mean I need an event which will trigger before the file has been created.

Comment: You want to change a file location before the file has been created?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I want

Comment: You can use the FileSystemWatch class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx), but I really don't think any event will be raised before a file has been partially created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried file system watcher but no luck, it will raise the event after file has been created

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: NO, you can't know that without third-party provider help.

You seems to be looking for an early indication that a file *will be* created. You must check on your third party application provider if they offer any hook for the event you're looking for, as probably will be lots of business rules in place.

As workaround, you can set up a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) object to monitor your default location and, if required, move the created file a more convenient location.

Comment: Actually the default file location was locked by bit locker, that is why I'm expecting earlier notification since the bitlocker will not allow to read the data

Comment: If you could inform the target file location, you set an unprotected location and afterwards move it to the default location.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: Actually I can't inform the default target location since it was generated through some other application

Comment: So you're deadlocked by the third-party application behavior and features; you'll need to ask them for guidance on your particular scenario

Answer (score 0):

Xavier,

Do you want to change the default location in the 3rd party app? Your question does not expose your ultimate goal.

Unless there are side effect from the file being created by the 3rd party app, or from said files disappearance, then you can try to 'head it off at the pass'.

Let the app create it's file. You can use FileSystemWatch class to 'intercept' the file once it's created. 
Your code can then move it to your new default folder and then invoke the app against that file. If the app needs the file to remain in that folder, then copy the file to your new location.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is simple, file will be created by third party application in a encrypted drive, my application trying to read the data from the protected drive, so it gets failed to access. Since it was third party application we were unable to change the default file location which is protected